# SPI timing on CS5480

Tags: spi, timing

Good day folks :)

i just want to know if i'm understanding it right? i read the datasheet and i saw the start-up row in the switching characteristics. Does every time - let's say i execute a command on a microcontroller to do SPI communication to a slave, will it always have a this start-up time delay then continue to sck + sdo??

[image]

[image]

i have this calculation of SPI data-in to the CS5480 ic in nanosecond unit, 10-bit transmission (1 start bit, 8 data bit, 1 stop bit)

[image]

am i doing it right?

would i have to include start-up time to my computation every time i do SPI transaction?

Hope you can help me on my dumb question since i am new to this and doing self study :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the oscillator start-up time is once when you power up the CPU. It can be repeated if you go come out of deep power down mode (I don't know: does the CS5480 have that). It is definitely not per instruction!

Comment: :D thanks a lot oldfart! this is what i really want to confirm well it doesn't have that but it has stand by mode where it will operate on low power only.